# My tablet won't boot

Tags: recovery-mode, boot

I just got a Arnova 10D G3 and it doesn't boot. All I get is the "Arnova" logo on a black screen. I bought it on a refurbished condition, it was a pretty good deal so I am ready to do any risky procedure to make it work since I don't have much to lose.

I downloaded the latest firmware from the official website but I am unable to use it because I can't access the recovery mode.

How can I make it boot?

UPDATE : I am now able to access the recovery mode (power + vol up) but the tablet keeps rebooting after loading this mode. I don't even have a menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution in this tutorial in French : http://forum.frandroid.com/topic/180104-tuto-flash-arnova-10dg3-rom-uberoid-jeally-bean-411-root%C3%A9e/

It seems like the firmware from Arnova is somehow incomplete. I installed a rooted ROM.